# How to do variable substitution in env_file?

Tags: docker-compose

I am using docker-compose and I want my env_file to have variable subsitution.  I would like to define one variable in the file and then use it in other variables:

```
APP_ENV=dev-foo
LOCALPATH=/tmp/builddir/${APP_ENV}
GIT_URL=git@github.com:some-org/${APP_ENV}
```

What is the supported form of variable substitutions in env_file???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable substitution is now [supported in docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/env-file/#parameter-expansion)

The syntax is similar to shell substitution.

#### Direct substitution

```
${VAR} -> value of VAR
```

#### Default value

```
${VAR:-default} -> value of VAR if set and non-empty, otherwise default
${VAR-default} -> value of VAR if set, otherwise default
```

#### Required value

```
${VAR:?error} -> value of VAR if set and non-empty, otherwise exit with error
${VAR?error} -> value of VAR if set, otherwise exit with error
```

#### Alternative value

```
${VAR:+replacement} -> replacement if VAR is set and non-empty, otherwise empty
${VAR+replacement} -> replacement if VAR is set, otherwise empty
```