# Docker environment file interpolation

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker .env file contents like following.

```
MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME=mysqldb
MYSQL_DATABASE=igmysqldb
MYSQL_DRIVER_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/igmysqldb
MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

I was wondering if i can do like following in the .env file.

```
MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME=mysqldb
MYSQL_DATABASE=igmysqldb
MYSQL_DRIVER_CLASS=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
MYSQL_DRIVER_URL=jdbc:mysql://MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME:MYSQL_PORT/MYSQL_DATABASE
MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

If docker allows to do the following in .env file ?

```
MYSQL_DRIVER_URL=jdbc:mysql://MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME:MYSQL_PORT/MYSQL_DATABASE
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do variable substitution in env\_file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277472/how-to-do-variable-substitution-in-env-file)

Comment: @Artemiy. Thats 2 years, 8 months ago. Nothing changed in these years ? :)